# How to Search in Google Map Api V2 Android?

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation, google-maps-markers, google-maps-api-2

I'm developing an Android application and using GoogleMaps API v2.
This application works so far but I want search in the map with a path:

Screenshot :

[image: GoogleMaps Screenshot]

my codes:

```
Position_mark = new LatLng(35.7008, 51.437);
map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(Position_mark, 15));
map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10), 2000, null);
map.setOnMapClickListener(this);
map.setOnMapLongClickListener(this);
map.setOnMarkerDragListener(this);
```

...

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    //Used to put dark icons on light action bar

    mGoItem = menu.add(0, Delete_ITEM_ID, 0, null);
    mGoItem.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
           .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);

    SearchView searchView = 
        new SearchView(getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext());
    searchView.setQueryHint("Search for Places…");
    searchView.setIconified(false);

    menu.add("Search")
        .setIcon(R.drawable.abs__ic_search)
        .setActionView(searchView)
        .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String newText) {
            return true;
        }

        /**
         * Called when the query text is changed by the user.
         * @param newText the new content of the query text field.
         * @return false if the SearchView should perform the 
         * default action of showing any suggestions if available, 
         * true if the action was handled by the listener.
         */
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), newText, 1).show();
            return true;
        }
    });

    return true;
}

@Override
public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // tvLocInfo.setText(point.toString());
    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(point));
    map.clear();

    Marker Kiel = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(point)
        .title("Kiel")
        .snippet("Kiel is cool").draggable(true)
        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
        .fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher)));
}
```

I use `ActionBarSherlock` and `SearchView` for searching. How to search in GoogleMaps API with path not latitute or longitude?

Answer (score 11):

You can use geocoding to search or see this nice tutorial which uses json parsing GoogleMaps.

- [Adding Google Places Autocomplete API as custom suggestions in Android Search Dialog](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/adding-google-places-autocomplete-api-as-custom-suggestions-in-android-search-dialog/)

Comment: this example is very good for me..thanks  http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-searchview-widget-with-google-places-api-using-actionbarsherlock-library

Comment: @Kavyan its not good to use geocoding for searching location in google map. because its not working in all devices..

Comment: @Segi It should work on the same devices that have access to the Google Maps V2 API (available through Play Services) because the geocoder in use is powered by maps