# Showing location on google map by passing area name in android

Tags: android

I want to show a `Google map v2` in my android app, I want to get city name on `Google map V2`. As i enter city name in edittext control. I have one `EditText`, if i enter the area name or city name in `EditText`, the map should show the passing area name into my google map.I am using `Google Map v2`.Any help will be appreciated.

This is my code on button search click.

```
btSearch.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


             try {
                    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(CreateReminderActivity.this);  

                    List<Address> addresses;

                    String areaname = edLocation.getText().toString();

                    addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(areaname, 1);

                    if(addresses.size() > 0) {

                        double latitude= addresses.get(0).getLatitude();

                        double longitude= addresses.get(0).getLongitude();

                        insLat = latitude;

                        insLong = longitude;

                        String statename = addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();



                        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .title(areaname)
                        .snippet("SNIPPET")
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher))
                        .anchor(0.0f, 1.0f) // Anchors the marker on the bottom left
                        .position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)));

                        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

                        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

                     // Zoom in the Google Map
                     googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10));


                     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), statename, 20).show();



                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }






        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search ?

You seem to be asking a very basic question.

Check this: [How to Search in Google Map Api V2 Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18192601/how-to-search-in-google-map-api-v2-android)

Comment: yeah, i knw  but the thing is that, i am not getting exect result, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Geocoder** for this purpose.

```
  try {
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this);  
        List<Address> addresses;
        addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName("PLACE_NAME", 1);
        if(addresses.size() > 0) {
            double latitude= addresses.get(0).getLatitude();
            double longitude= addresses.get(0).getLongitude();
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .title("TITLE")
            .snippet("SNIPPET")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher))
            .anchor(0.0f, 1.0f) // Anchors the marker on the bottom left
            .position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)));
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: yeah, i did this, but not showing what i exactly want, i am checking it again. thank you.